# How to render component only once in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using Expo + React Navigation.

There are many screens in my React Native apps which use a component `Map`. I don't want this component to be re-rendered whenever switching screen. Are there any way to save my component `Map` to some kind of storage so that every time I need `Map`, my app doesn't have to re-render it?

Comment: Are you using any tab navigators?

Comment: I am using StackNavigator from `react-navigation`

Comment: You can make use of shouldComponentUpdate(). Just return false from this method and it will make sure that the component doesn't gets updated. Note that this method is not called during the mounting phase, so this will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something should not re-render. You gave that in index page. If your give it in index page it can be access everywhere in project.

**Example:**

Whenever I use firebase I initialize firebase in index.js file.

Comment: But how can you access it in any screen?

Comment: In my case I used firebase. I initialize firebase in index.js file. If I want to access firebase wherever in my component  I simply call   - "import * as firebase from 'firebase';". It help me to access.

Comment: I am using a `Map` here and it is initialized first when the app starts. However, it keeps re-rendering every time switching screens. I think what you suggest doesn't work in my case because my component is initialized in the beginning just like your firebase.

Comment: Sorry! yet I did not have experience in Map concept. I will let you know once I get answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you could play with `shouldComponentUpdate()` of you Map component.

Try to return `true` only for the first render and then return `false` for feature calls to tell React not to re-render your component.

Answer (score 0):

react-native works with virtual dom, when you switch to another screen, I think first screen is removed from the dom in which you have your map component, so it will be re rendered when you come back. what you can do is you can render the map component at parent level where u r switching screens and pass it as children to your screen. this is one solution but don't know whether its a best one

Answer (score 0):

What if you cache your Map data on first render and then use cached data second time for faster rendering?

I would suggest you to go through the `Map` docs to look for any caching prop or just include any third party `Map` component that supports caching.